# javascript fetch() works with breakpoints, but fails with TypeError when run normally

Tags: javascript, fetch, typeerror

I'm trying to fetch() text/plain data from a remote service. If I place a breakpoint in the promise "then" chain, the text data from the server is available. Without the breakpoint, I get a fetch() exception.

I am using a prototype design pattern (see below). When I place a breakpoint in the "then" chain as shown below, the data from the remote service is successfully retrieved. Without the breakpoint, the catch() is executed and the error is:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I'm totally stumped and would appreciate any help!

Note, the server (a python app) sends back html, with

```
self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Also, if I use Ajax (FWIW, it works). I'd like to get it working with fetch() however.

```
function Fetch(Msg) {
   // Msg contains some info on how to construct the JSON message to transmit -- not relevant here.
    this.help = `
        The Fetch object specifies communication basics using
        the fetch(...) mechanism. 
    `;
    // some misc object vars...
}

Fetch.prototype = {
    constructor: Fetch,

    postData: async function (url = '', data = {}) {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method:         'POST,
            mode:           'cors',
            cache:          'no-cache',
            credentials:    'same-origin',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            },
            redirect:       'follow',                   
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',              
            // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        return await response.text(); // 
    },

    handleErrorsInResponse: function (response) {
        var debug = new Debug("Fetch.handleErrorsInResponse");
        debug.entering();
        debug.leaving();
    },

    handleReponse: function (response) {
        var debug = new Debug("Fetch.handleResponse");
        debug.entering();
        console.log(response);
        debug.leaving();
    },

    handleErrorsInFetch: function (response) {
        var debug = new Debug("Fetch.handleErrorsInFetch");
        debug.entering();
        console.log(response);
        debug.leaving();
    },

    call: function (payload) {
        this.postData(
            'http://some.url/',
            payload)
        .then(this.handleErrorsInResponse)  // If I place a breakpoint here it works!
        .then(this.handleReponse)
        .catch(this.handleErrorsInFetch);
    },
}

// Ultimately called by something like
comms = new Fetch();
someData = {"key": someJSON};
comms.call(someData);
```

Comment: Does `http://some.url/` have CORS headers?  Do they match your origin?

Comment: The server (python app) sends: 

```self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")```

If there was some CORS issue, why would the above code work when breakpointed?

Comment: What other errors are you getting in the console ?

Comment: FYI, `handleErrorsInResponse` and `handleReponse` are not async, so a `.then` after `handleErrorsInResponse` is not useful. Also, if you are going to use `async`/`await`, consider going "all in" and not dropping back to `.then` and `.catch`.

Comment: @sohail:
```
 --------> Entering Fetch.handleErrorsInFetch...
 In Fetch.handleErrorsInFetch: 
response = 
TypeError: Failed to fetch
Leaving Fetch.handleErrorsInFetch --------> ```

The Entering/Leaving decorators are the Debug object noise

@crashmstr:

What does "going all in" mean?

Comment: Note that `call` is a function that is already defined on `Function.prototype`. You may want to rename that.

Comment: @RudolphPienaar Going all in means that you `const response = await this.postData(...); handleErrorsInResponse(response)` etc.

Comment: Anyway, I am sorry that I am not able to give you a solution. All I can say is that your code does look right and I totally agree with crashmstr's advice that it might be worth rewriting the code using either just promises or just async await (personally would recommend the latter). If nothing else it will make it easier to see what's happening exactly at each stage.

Comment: No worries @DavidMulder -- I appreciate the thoughts. I guess at some level I don't fully grok the model. If just feels like some weird timing thing, too... as evidenced by the fact that when I manually step over the code it works, but otherwise is unreliable.

Comment: Had the same problem. Reason was that fetch was called when a button in a form was clicked. Unwantedly form was submitted so page was reloaded and fetch failed. That was why it would not happen if you set a breakpoint and delay page reload.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the wait on the response.

Replace

```
return await response.text();
```

by

```
return response.text();
```

Comment: The response object returned by a fetch is a `Promise` too, it needs to be awaited.

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis Fairly certain that when you have a promise returning a promise, both will be awaited for the resolution of the outer promise. So if I am not wrong on that count then both pieces of code would be functionally equivalent. Practically speaking though I could be wrong where there might be a difference between `await` and `then`, not sure.

Comment: if you have an async function you are supposed to return a promise, so awaiting it is not necessary as the function itself is going to be awaited. So i guess @mdev is right

Comment: @GeorgePasquali When you have an async function the return value is automatically wrapped in a promise, so you should *not* return a promise. If you're returning a promise it kind of defeats part of the point of using an async method

Comment: Ok --  weirdly, when I followed this suggestion, it worked! Mostly... and therein lies the complexity that I don't understand. Sometimes the response is now caught, but occasionally I still catch an error. 

Also, no one has had insights into why this all works when I have an explicit breakpoint. With the breakpoint, when I have to manually hit "Continue" it works. Every. Single. Time. 

This suggests there is some timing issue that I don't fully understand.